# Orthonormalize a vector against an orthonormal set

Tags: lapack

I can orthonormalize a set of m n-dimensional (m < n) vectors by successive calls to lapack's `dgeqrf` and `dorgqr`. Now suppose I have a new vector, which I want to orthonormalize with respect to the previous set. Would, in general, a new call to `dgeqrf` and `dorgqr`, with the corresponding extended matrix, be efficient? Or would it be a waste of time, because it would operate on the first m vectors anyway, despite the fact they are already orthonormal? Would the answer change if I have k new vectors instead of just one?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that `dgeqrf` and `dorgqr` will ignore the fact that the first m vectors are already orthogonal. If you just add a new vector to the m first vectors `u_i`, the Gram–Schmidt process may be what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

But it may also be a bad idea if you add many vectors or if your problem is sensitive to numerical errors.

Bye,

Francis

Comment: I don't use lapack, but I know that using Gram-Schmidt leads to numerical errors if you apply it on many vectors, this is why it is advised to used Householder reflections instead (read more about it on the Wikipedia entry of QR decomposition)